# celery python threading with function importing

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I'm working in python and was originally using someone's code to thread and render a map with mapnik. I've since tried to put it into a flask API, with celery as a backend.

Originally:
https://gist.github.com/Thetoxicarcade/57777a6714cb6fecaacf

"add an api":
https://gist.github.com/Thetoxicarcade/079cf03a3f3a061134f2

(yes I will edit this to make it shorter and better)

In general:

flask -> search(params) -> runCelery(params) -> returnOkay
celery worker (gimme params) -> fork a bunch of threads, render that place

*I may just rewrite this into a billion celery tasks?

except everything in runCelery is in the dark.

the worker task itself:

```
"""background working map algorithm"""
# I have no clue with these celery declarations.
CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
worker = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='redis://localhost')
@worker.task(name="Renderer")#bind=True
def async_render(key,minz,maxz,fake):
    from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

    logs = logging.getLogger('brettapi')
    file = logging.FileHandler('/home/aristatek/log{}'.format(key))
    style = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    file.setFormatter(style)
    logs.addHandler(file)
    logs.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logs.debug('HELLO WORLD')
    logs.debug('I AM {}'.format(key))



    #osm file
    home = os.environ['HOME']
    tiledir = home + "/mapnik/mapnik/osm.xml"
    #grab minz/maxz
    if minz is None: minz = 6
    if maxz is None: maxz = 17
    name=reverseKey(key)
    bounds=makeBorder(key)
    file = home + "/mapnik/mapnik/tiles/" + name + "/"
    print key,minz,maxz,fake,file, tiledir, name
    print bounds
    # polygons are defined by lowercase, spaceless name strings. (or they were.)
    if fake is not True:
        bbox = (-180, -90, 180, 90)
        render_tiles(bbox, tiledir, file, 0, 5, "World")
        render_tiles(bounds, tiledir, file, minz, maxz, name)
    return "Finished"
```

Apparently, any way that I try to get these celery instances to respond with logs or process information, they refuse to do so, which makes debugging them really tough.

I started a celery worker and was able to start celeryflower. I cannot seem to queue the task at all, and see nothing happening. :/

Part of this may be that I'm not importing functions, but even using pdb isn't helpful because of the mysticism of celery objects not obeying anything I throw at them.

It's a vague question because I hardly understand it anyway. The "read the docs" pages for celery are about as vague as possible. Do they mean properties or functions or variables within celery?? within the workers??

I'd like to know a way to get celery to respond, which would be meaningful because it means I'm going in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit -

Turns out from most of this the names declared need to be their own:

```
def things(key):
   thread_lots(key)
worker = Celery()
@worker.task(name='ThisTask')
def ThisTask(key):
   from testme import things
   things(key)

webserve = Flask()
@webserve.route('/bla')
def bla(key):
   ThisTask.apply_async((params), task_id=key)
```

Comment: you almost certainly have a configuration problem. write a simple test task, play around with celeryconfig.py, broker configuration, the workers command line etc until you can get that to work.

Comment: okay. I stripped everything out, but celery still gets mad about 'no attribute user_options' https://gist.github.com/Thetoxicarcade/c62f3546b09b64877868

Comment: okay. I think celery likes the configs now. The import doesn't make sense for me, and my task "Renderer" isn't registered. I broke flower somehow. How am I supposed to read their documentation it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: we run celery on a 128 cpu cluster, I've read the celery documentation quite a lot. believe me, with a bit of effort it makes sense. please go over it a few more times. then please figure out exactly what bits you don't understand and then ask specific questions on this site - this question here is too vague and broad.

Comment: how do I register a function within celery (and where, because it's not explained). For instance, file.functionOne in celery worker ABC, which should respond to file.flaskStuff, even if they're seperate.

Comment: I know I'm incredibly vague, I'm sorry.

Comment: that question doesn't make much sense to me. try following the getting started guide, and adapt the examples to your needs: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application

Comment: I did eventually get it working. It involved having the same name in the decorator, with the right namespace. I stopped trying to convert the flask into anything else.

Comment: again... not realy sure what you're saying. but good that you got it working.